# Iterate through directories randomly leads to truncated paths

Tags: linux, bash, youtube-dl

I'm running a Bash script which goes through a directory containing videos and re-download them (using youtube-dl) in order to update the meta-data. The problem is that in case some has to be downloaded (because the original video has changed) the current path must to be provided. That's no problem in itself but I've noticed that after a loop where youtube-dl has been called the absolute path is truncated.

I still can't find the error pattern. The truncation is always different but the path truncated is always the same, but one thing is sure, if youtube-dl is no called, all the paths are complete.

```
#!/bin/bash
path="$1"
youtube_regex=".*\([a-zA-Z0-9_-]\{11\}\)^*";
vimeo_regex=".*\-\([0-9]\{8\}\).^*";

while read -d '' filename;
do
    echo "FILE: $filename";
    #directoryname="$(dirname "$filename")";
    directoryname="${filename%/*}";
    cd "$directoryname";
    echo "WORKING DIRECTORY: `pwd`";
    echo "ABSOLUTE PATH + LOCAL FILENAME: $filename";
    video_id=`expr "$filename" : $youtube_regex`;

    if [ -n "$video_id" ];
    then
        video_url="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=$video_id";
    else
        video_id=`expr "$filename" : $vimeo_regex`;
        video_url="https://vimeo.com/$video_id";

        if [ -z "$video_id" ];
        then
            echo "VIDEO ID: NULL";
        fi;
    fi;

    if [ -n "$video_url" ];
    then
        youtube-dl "$video_url"; # <- this seems to be the cause
    else
        echo 'METADATA DOWNLOAD UNSUCESSFUL';
    fi;

    echo '+-----------------------------------------+';
    echo '|          FILE PROCESS FINISHED          |';
    echo '+-----------------------------------------+';
done < <(find "$path" -type f \( -name \*mp4 -or -name \*flv -or -name \*webm \) -print0);
```

EDIT: this is an example of the error (if you want to see the truncated paths, just look for the blocks with the message `ERROR: Interrupted by user`).

```
nelson@triplecero:~$ ./write_video_metadata.sh /media/SAMSUNG/Video/
FILE: /media/SAMSUNG/Video/Music Videos/Bass Guitar/Yolanda Charles  and Phil Gould - Bass Syncopation Exercise-T3Lszt2HPK8.mp4
WORKING DIRECTORY: /media/SAMSUNG/Video/Music Videos/Bass Guitar
ABSOLUTE PATH + LOCAL FILENAME: /media/SAMSUNG/Video/Music Videos/Bass Guitar/Yolanda Charles  and Phil Gould - Bass Syncopation Exercise-T3Lszt2HPK8.mp4
[youtube] T3Lszt2HPK8: Downloading webpage
[youtube] T3Lszt2HPK8: Extracting video information
[youtube] T3Lszt2HPK8: Looking for automatic captions
WARNING: Couldn't find automatic captions for T3Lszt2HPK8
WARNING: video doesn't have subtitles
[download] Yolanda Charles  and Phil Gould - Bass Syncopation Exercise-T3Lszt2HPK8.mp4 has already been downloaded
[ffmpeg] Adding metadata to 'Yolanda Charles  and Phil Gould - Bass Syncopation Exercise-T3Lszt2HPK8.mp4'
+-----------------------------------------+
|          FILE PROCESS FINISHED          |
+-----------------------------------------+
FILE: hgQ.mp4
./write_video_metadata.sh: línea 30: cd: hgQ.mp4: No existe el fichero o el directorio
WORKING DIRECTORY: /media/SAMSUNG/Video/Music Videos/Bass Guitar
ABSOLUTE PATH + LOCAL FILENAME: hgQ.mp4
VIDEO ID: NULL
[generic] vimeo: Requesting header
WARNING: Falling back on generic information extractor.
[generic] vimeo: Downloading webpage
[generic] vimeo: Extracting information
[download] Resuming download at byte 465123
[download] Destination: Vimeo, Your Videos Belong Here-yosemite_hd_ii_hd.webm
[download]   1.5% of 77.29MiB at 161.94KiB/s ETA 08:01^C
ERROR: Interrupted by user
+-----------------------------------------+
|          FILE PROCESS FINISHED          |
+-----------------------------------------+
FILE: /media/SAMSUNG/Video/Music Videos/100 best music videos of all time/Metallica - Turn The Page-dOibtqWo6z4.mp4
WORKING DIRECTORY: /media/SAMSUNG/Video/Music Videos/100 best music videos of all time
ABSOLUTE PATH + LOCAL FILENAME: /media/SAMSUNG/Video/Music Videos/100 best music videos of all time/Metallica - Turn The Page-dOibtqWo6z4.mp4
[youtube] dOibtqWo6z4: Downloading webpage
[youtube] dOibtqWo6z4: Extracting video information
[youtube] dOibtqWo6z4: Looking for automatic captions
[youtube] dOibtqWo6z4: Downloading XML
WARNING: video doesn't have subtitles
[info] Writing video subtitles to: Metallica - Turn The Page-dOibtqWo6z4.en.srt
[info] Writing video subtitles to: Metallica - Turn The Page-dOibtqWo6z4.es.srt
[download] Metallica - Turn The Page-dOibtqWo6z4.mp4 has already been downloaded
[ffmpeg] Adding metadata to 'Metallica - Turn The Page-dOibtqWo6z4.mp4'
+-----------------------------------------+
|          FILE PROCESS FINISHED          |
+-----------------------------------------+
FILE: ive in Harlem/Gorillaz - Feel Good Inc (Live in Harlem)-1wuPOY-TDk4.mp4
./write_video_metadata.sh: línea 30: cd: ive in Harlem: No existe el fichero o el directorio
WORKING DIRECTORY: /media/SAMSUNG/Video/Music Videos/100 best music videos of all time
ABSOLUTE PATH + LOCAL FILENAME: ive in Harlem/Gorillaz - Feel Good Inc (Live in Harlem)-1wuPOY-TDk4.mp4
[youtube] 1wuPOY-TDk4: Downloading webpage
[youtube] 1wuPOY-TDk4: Extracting video information
[youtube] 1wuPOY-TDk4: Looking for automatic captions
WARNING: Couldn't find automatic captions for 1wuPOY-TDk4
WARNING: video doesn't have subtitles
[download] Destination: Gorillaz - Feel Good Inc (Live in Harlem)-1wuPOY-TDk4.mp4
[download]   1.3% of 15.37MiB at 147.45KiB/s ETA 01:45^C
ERROR: Interrupted by user
+-----------------------------------------+
|          FILE PROCESS FINISHED          |
+-----------------------------------------+
FILE: /media/SAMSUNG/Video/Music Videos/Gorillaz/thegreatmonster/Gorillaz - Spitting Out The Demons-MPn7l5a9sKg.mp4
WORKING DIRECTORY: /media/SAMSUNG/Video/Music Videos/Gorillaz/thegreatmonster
ABSOLUTE PATH + LOCAL FILENAME: /media/SAMSUNG/Video/Music Videos/Gorillaz/thegreatmonster/Gorillaz - Spitting Out The Demons-MPn7l5a9sKg.mp4
[youtube] MPn7l5a9sKg: Downloading webpage
[youtube] MPn7l5a9sKg: Extracting video information
[youtube] MPn7l5a9sKg: Looking for automatic captions
WARNING: Couldn't find automatic captions for MPn7l5a9sKg
WARNING: video doesn't have subtitles
[download] Gorillaz - Spitting Out The Demons-MPn7l5a9sKg.mp4 has already been downloaded
[ffmpeg] Adding metadata to 'Gorillaz - Spitting Out The Demons-MPn7l5a9sKg.mp4'
+-----------------------------------------+
|          FILE PROCESS FINISHED          |
+-----------------------------------------+
FILE: n TODOBAJOS TV - Introducción al flamenco II-j28g33HAQ6E.mp4
./write_video_metadata.sh: línea 30: cd: n TODOBAJOS TV - Introducción al flamenco II-j28g33HAQ6E.mp4: No existe el fichero o el directorio
WORKING DIRECTORY: /media/SAMSUNG/Video/Music Videos/Gorillaz/thegreatmonster
ABSOLUTE PATH + LOCAL FILENAME: n TODOBAJOS TV - Introducción al flamenco II-j28g33HAQ6E.mp4
[youtube] j28g33HAQ6E: Downloading webpage
[youtube] j28g33HAQ6E: Extracting video information
[youtube] j28g33HAQ6E: Looking for automatic captions
WARNING: Couldn't find automatic captions for j28g33HAQ6E
WARNING: video doesn't have subtitles
[download] Resuming download at byte 64512
[download] Destination: (2_3) CARLES BENAVENT en TODOBAJOS TV - Introducción al flamenco II-j28g33HAQ6E.mp4
[download]   0.2% of 49.65MiB at 150.71KiB/s ETA 05:36^C
ERROR: Interrupted by user
+-----------------------------------------+
|          FILE PROCESS FINISHED          |
+-----------------------------------------+
FILE: /media/SAMSUNG/Video/Music Videos/TodobajosTV/(5_5) CHARLIE MORENO en TODOBAJOS TV - SOLO-4Z1zoVq-FwY.mp4
WORKING DIRECTORY: /media/SAMSUNG/Video/Music Videos/TodobajosTV
ABSOLUTE PATH + LOCAL FILENAME: /media/SAMSUNG/Video/Music Videos/TodobajosTV/(5_5) CHARLIE MORENO en TODOBAJOS TV - SOLO-4Z1zoVq-FwY.mp4
^Z
[1]+  Detenido                ./write_video_metadata.sh /media/SAMSUNG/Video/
nelson@triplecero:~$
```

Comment: What is being truncated exactly? Do you mean the path given to `youtube-dl` is not the full path it should be? What does `echo "$video_url"` show if you put it right above that `youtube-dl` call? What is `$video_id` at that point?

Comment: There is no need to be terminating every line with semi-colons, consider using `$(..)` instead of the legacy use of backticks and double-quote `$variables` to prevent globbing and word splitting.

Comment: @EtanReisner: the truncation is in the paths (and sometimes in the file names), as I said, a random behavior. If I comment the line calling to the youtube-dl command, everything seems to works perfectly fine.

Comment: @user3439894: I was thinking about the semicolon thing some weeks, but I didn't seems to be important (obviously it's junk code, so I will delete them eventually).

Comment: Those paths are "incorrect" as soon as you enter the loop. The `youtube-dl` call is entirely unrelated. Look at the `FILE` output lines. Can you just run that `find` command manually and find the entries for those incorrect paths and show us what they look like? You'll want to pipe the output to `cat -v` or similar to get the NULLs to be visible.

Comment: @user3439894: I'll try your advise about replacing back-ticks and double quoting with variable expansion, maybe that's the problem comes from.

Comment: @EtanReisner: I've just updated the post, please have I read of it. I've just comment (once again) the calling line to youtube-dl, but echoing the ``$video_url`` just before... and it's always perfect (as the absolute path to it).

Comment: Oh! `youtube-dl` is probably reading from standard input for some reason and stealing from your shell loop. Redirect stdin for `youtube-dl` (`</dev/null`) and I bet the problem does away. Though you might want to find out what it is trying to read input for (use a different fd for `find` and `read` to see it).

Comment: @EtanReisner: my bash script has been running for hours with no problem soever (I only had to put a ``continue`` statement inside the second ``if``), so your solution was the right one. Thanks so much! :-)

Comment: A `continue` where? There's only an echo block after the second `if`. Do you mean you didn't want that big block printed if you didn't run `youtube-dl` on it this time? Moving that echo block into the `if` would have worked for that too.

Comment: @EtanReisner: Just after the ``echo "VIDEO ID: NULL";`` line. Because if none of those video ID are present in the filename, youtube-dl must not be invoked (specially in the case of Vimeo). 
I think it would be better to re-factor the code using ``case`` instead nested ``if``.

Comment: Unsetting `video_url` would have worked there too (and would have gotten you the `METADATA DOWNLOAD UNSUCESSFUL` and `FINISHED` output for those entries. As would only setting `video_url` if `video_id` had contents but ok.

Comment: @EtanReisner: that makes more sense!